# Using a canvas on top of an image to show visuals relating to image properties read of a list box

Tags: c#, wpf

We have images created off a a high resolution scanner for showing defects on glass products. Our C# application is used by clients to manage defects. Many customers are having difficulties translating the image properties like actual length provided. I am working with a base image with a canvas on top. I also have a grid with a list of properties which when selected, I want to show a visual on how to translate the selection by say, drawing a line on the canvas in a manner that depicts the translation.

Comment: Tried to include code snippets, but an error seems to occur every time saying code is not indented well.

Comment: Indent code with four whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the requirement was misconstrued and what was needed was creating simulations on separate images that I had to create and load. Next time I will try to think outside the box.